# Working on a Compressed File in Stages

Tags: shell, gzip

Okay so I have a cache file for a script of mine which is basically just a list of file-paths, but I like to keep it gzipped as it can otherwise get pretty huge.

However, within my script I need to read it line-by-line, however I'm currently doing this by simply decompressing the whole file into `/tmp` and reading it from there using a file-descriptor (via `exec`) so I can `read` from it each time I need the next entry.

Anyway, I wanted to know if there is a more efficient way that I could be doing this; I know how to read a file line by line by piping the output of `gzip` into a loop, however I only read lines from the cache file periodically, i.e - I'm already looping from a different set of data so I can't read from the cache that way too.

Is there any way that I can read the contents of a gzipped file directly in a line-by-line way (doesn't need to use `read`) without having to expand it fully first, and without using a loop? If possible I'd appreciate an example of how to write a file in the same way, for when I need to create/update the cache file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest something along these lines, if you don't want reading from your compressed file to impact reading from your other files, or if the times you want to read from it are irregular with respect to the rest of your logic flow:

```
exec 3< <(zcat compressedfile.gz)

while read other stuff from other file
do

  # ...

  if ${sometimes}
    read -u3 get stuff from compressed file

  # ...

done < other_file

exec 3<&-
```

Comment: That seems to do the trick nicely! I'm not sure I can use `read -u3` on my platform, but `read line <&3` seems to work as expected, I assume they're identical in behaviour? Thanks!

Comment: If you're running a recent enough `bash` to grok the `exec 3< <(...)` bit, then `read -u3` should not be an issue...

Comment: Okay, so yeah while this feature is available on my Linux test box, I'm not sure OS X supports it (at least Mountain Lion doesn't seem to), are there any other alternatives? And how about for writing?

Comment: I'm not particularly familiar with OS X, but I would suggest 1) make sure you're really using `bash` and not something masquerading as it, 2) old versions of `bash` still had coprocesses, I believe, which functioned similarly to process substitution, but were a bit more difficult to code properly for - check the man page for the version you have, 3) if you aren't really using `bash` check the appropriate man page to see what abilities your shell actually has, and 3) possibly install additional packages to get newer shell versions...

Comment: Also regarding your question about writing, if you're using a shell that supports `<(...)`, it should also support `>(...)`. Read the section on process substitution in the manual page for additional information.

Answer (score 0):

`zcat` is what you need to read a file as it was plain text. The complete shell code could look like this:
`zcat <file> | while read line; do.....; done` but take care about subshell issues: `while` is executed in a sub-shell and thus changes to variables aren't seen in the 'main' script.  If this is a problem for you then you need a more complex solution to pipe your cache file.